# How to make Graphql run with CORS

Tags: graphql

I've read several articles about this, but none of them work for me.

https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/issues/14

Here is my expressjs code:

```
app.use("/graphql", function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});


// apply graphql middleware
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: rootResolver,
  graphiql: true,
}))
```

If I do it this way, the pre-flight OPTIONS is successful, but the actual POST request fails.

I am using this function to make request to local graphql server.

```
function postFn(url, payload) {
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    },
    data: payload
  });
}
```

Here is the front-end code to trigger the POST request:

```
  let query = `
    query myqury($offset: Int, $limit: Int) {
      clients(limit:$limit , offset:$offset ) {
        docs{
          _id
          full_name
        }
        total
        limit
        offset
      }
    }
  `
  var variables = {
    offset: offset,
    limit: limit
  }
  let payload = {
    query: query,
    variables: variables
  }
  return request.post(graphQlEndpoint, payload)
```

The error message is:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue as you. Using the graphQL on an express server.

Try using express [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

Use it in your express code like this

```js
const express = require( `express` );
const graphqlHTTP = require( `express-graphql` );
const cors = require( `cors` );
const app = express();

app.use( cors() );
app.use(
    `/graphql`,
    graphqlHTTP( {
        schema: schema, // point to your schema 
        rootValue: rootResolver, // point to your resolver 
        graphiql: true
    } )
);
```

Fetch example based on [GraphQL Documentation](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/graphql-clients/)

```js
fetch( url, {
    method : `post`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': `application/json`,
        'Accept'      : `application/json`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify( {
        query: `
        {
            person {
                name
            }
        }`
    } )
} )
.then( response => response.json() )
.then( response => console.log( response ) );
```

Comment: Interestin choice of quotes (backtick templates rather than string literals) but good answer, i just put cors() in and hey presto! what a great day

Comment: I normally only use backticks not sure why I used single quotes on this occasion. But it means I can easily use es6 string interpolation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when making calls using Vue client. The only way I could resolve was to disable the Cross-Origin restriction on the browser for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Please insert below code in your server.js file

```js
const graphQLServer = express();
const corsOptions = {
    origin(origin, callback) {
        callback(null, true);
    },
    credentials: true
};
graphQLServer.use(cors(corsOptions));
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,token');
    next();
}
graphQLServer.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

I think this may solve your problem

Comment: Unless this is a public API, disabling all CORS security (what this answer recommends) is a large security risk.

Comment: where is `cors` defined?

Comment: and where is origin defined?